# Nginx doesn't support architecture i386

Tags: kubuntu, nginx

When I want to update my system `sudo apt-get update` the following error occur:

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'nginx/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu jammy InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

I've tried to edit `nginx.list` inside of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and I changed

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg] http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu jammy nginx
```

with

```
deb [arch=amd64] http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu/ bionic nginx
```

However that provoked another errors such are:

```
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY
```

Any help?
Kubuntu 22.04 LTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using any 22.04 variant, then you should not *need* i386 packages for the most part.  32-bit i386 as an OS is *dead* in Ubuntu for the most part.  However, some drivers and software has i386 bits hence why your system is still 'multi-arch' checking for i386 drivers.

However, you can tell this easily to work - combine the strings you use in the arguments for the `deb` definition line.  Use this string which combines the two you were using:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg arch=amd64] http://nginx.org/packages/mainline/ubuntu jammy nginx
```

This will use the proper signing key AND only search for amd64 packages.

Comment: Perfect! That solved the issue, thank you.